# Reason for uncertainty in python-requests ConnectionError [10061]

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-requests

I am using requests and BeautifulSoup to download the higher resolution images by iterating through the links parsed from their thumbnails using BeautifulSoup on a web page.
 
**Making multiple connections with the requests module in python [2.7] on my system could run smoothly sometimes and it could also get aborted midway on the very next run, with the following error:**

```
File "G:\imgDownloader.py", line 69, in imageSearch
    dwdPage = requests.get(dwdLink)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 69, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 50, in request
    response = session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 465, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 573, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 415, in send
    raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', error(10061, 'No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it'))
```

*My system is connected to the Internet through college LAN (via Proxifier) (I don't know if this is important, so pardon me)*.

**If use of session is required, then why is not there a certainity in execution/abortion behavior?**

Comment: The *remote* server is refusing connections. Perhaps you are being rate limited?

Comment: Thanks @MartijnPieters. I can understand this part, but not the inherent design/logic of these rate and session things! That is, why is rate limitation not happening every time?

Comment: I have no idea, that depends on what kind of rate limiting system is in place.

Comment: Oh, but thanks anyways. So where should I be looking to learn more then?